# na.pad not working in diff() function

Tags: r

For some reason the diff() functions na.pad parameter is not working properly? Anyone else having this problem or have a work around?

```
yo <- c(5,3,3,4,5,6,5,8,9)
diff(yo, na.pad = TRUE)

[1] -2  0  1  1  1 -1  3  1
```

The resulting vector should be:

```
[1] NA -2  0  1  1  1 -1  3  1
```

Comment: Is that functionality really expected to work? It doesn't work on my session either.

Comment: It should its in the documentation

Comment: `na.pad` is not a parameter to `diff.default`.  see `?diff`

Comment: It's possiable I was looking at diff() in the xts package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `diff` you use certainly comes from `xts` package, `na.pad` does not apply on base `R` vectors. And you also need to convert your vector to times series:

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)

yy = zoo(yo)
diff(yy, na.pad=TRUE)

# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
#NA -2  0  1  1  1 -1  3  1
```